# Attempting a naive implementation of the MD5 hash in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, md5

For the sake of the exercise, I'm trying to implement the MD5 hash algorithm as found on Wikipedia, in Java.

I compare the result of my implementation to the one returned by the JDK's implementation. I'm not trying to figure out the best, most elegant, most efficient, implementation yet. Just one that works.

It seems my implementation yields the correct result only half the time, and I can't figure why.

```
public static String md5DigestHexString(String message) {

    int[] s = { 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 5, 9, 14, 20, 5, 9, 14, 20, 5, 9, 14,
            20, 5, 9, 14, 20, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15,
            21, 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21 };

    int[] K = { 0xd76aa478, 0xe8c7b756, 0x242070db, 0xc1bdceee, 0xf57c0faf, 0x4787c62a, 0xa8304613, 0xfd469501,
            0x698098d8, 0x8b44f7af, 0xffff5bb1, 0x895cd7be, 0x6b901122, 0xfd987193, 0xa679438e, 0x49b40821,
            0xf61e2562, 0xc040b340, 0x265e5a51, 0xe9b6c7aa, 0xd62f105d, 0x02441453, 0xd8a1e681, 0xe7d3fbc8,
            0x21e1cde6, 0xc33707d6, 0xf4d50d87, 0x455a14ed, 0xa9e3e905, 0xfcefa3f8, 0x676f02d9, 0x8d2a4c8a,
            0xfffa3942, 0x8771f681, 0x6d9d6122, 0xfde5380c, 0xa4beea44, 0x4bdecfa9, 0xf6bb4b60, 0xbebfbc70,
            0x289b7ec6, 0xeaa127fa, 0xd4ef3085, 0x04881d05, 0xd9d4d039, 0xe6db99e5, 0x1fa27cf8, 0xc4ac5665,
            0xf4292244, 0x432aff97, 0xab9423a7, 0xfc93a039, 0x655b59c3, 0x8f0ccc92, 0xffeff47d, 0x85845dd1,
            0x6fa87e4f, 0xfe2ce6e0, 0xa3014314, 0x4e0811a1, 0xf7537e82, 0xbd3af235, 0x2ad7d2bb, 0xeb86d391 };

    int a0 = 0x67452301; // A
    int b0 = 0xefcdab89; // B
    int c0 = 0x98badcfe; // C
    int d0 = 0x10325476; // D


    byte[] msgInBytes = message.getBytes();

    int tempMsgTotalNbOfBytes = msgInBytes.length + 1 + 8;
    int modOfMsgInBytes = tempMsgTotalNbOfBytes % 64;

    int nbOfZeroBytesNeeded = 0;
    if (modOfMsgInBytes > 0)
        nbOfZeroBytesNeeded = 64 - modOfMsgInBytes;

    tempMsgTotalNbOfBytes += nbOfZeroBytesNeeded;

    byte[] finalTabForMsgInBytesToDigest = Arrays.copyOf(msgInBytes, tempMsgTotalNbOfBytes);

    finalTabForMsgInBytesToDigest[msgInBytes.length] = (byte) 128;

    long msgLengthInBits = (long) msgInBytes.length * 8;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

        finalTabForMsgInBytesToDigest[tempMsgTotalNbOfBytes - 8 + i] = (byte) msgLengthInBits;

        msgLengthInBits >>>= 8;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < finalTabForMsgInBytesToDigest.length; i += 64) {
        int A = a0;
        int B = b0;
        int C = c0;
        int D = d0;
        int F = 0, g = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
            if (0 <= j && j <= 15) {
                F = (B & C) | ((~B) & D);
                g = j;
            } else if (16 <= j & j <= 31) {
                F = (D & B) | ((~D) & C);
                g = (5 * j + 1) % 16;
            } else if (32 <= j && j <= 47) {
                F = B ^ C ^ D;
                g = (3 * j + 5) % 16;
            } else if (48 <= j && j <= 63) {
                F = C ^ (B | (~D));
                g = (7 * j) % 16;
            }
            int chunk = finalTabForMsgInBytesToDigest[i + g * 4 + 3] << 24;
            chunk |= finalTabForMsgInBytesToDigest[i + g * 4 + 2] << 16;
            chunk |= finalTabForMsgInBytesToDigest[i + g * 4 + 1] << 8;
            chunk |= finalTabForMsgInBytesToDigest[i + g * 4];

            F = F + A + K[j] + chunk;
            A = D;
            D = C;
            C = B;
            B = B + Integer.rotateLeft(F, s[j]);
        }

        a0 = a0 + A;
        b0 = b0 + B;
        c0 = c0 + C;
        d0 = d0 + D;
    }
    byte[] md5 = new byte[16];
    int count = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        int n = (k == 0) ? a0 : ((k == 1) ? b0 : ((k == 2) ? c0 : d0));
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            md5[count] = (byte) n;
            count++;
            n >>>= 8;
        }
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int l = 0; l < md5.length; l++) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X", md5[l] & 0xFF));
    }
    return sb.toString().toLowerCase();
}
```

Here are a few test results:

```
Message : bca
my MD5 : b64eab8ce39e013604e243089c687e4f
JV MD5 : b64eab8ce39e013604e243089c687e4f

Message : helmo
my MD5 : 307efe36da7042dbbb254ba88ccb38a3
JV MD5 : 40eb7df9494c88d9f0302dea74c6c327

Message : hello world
my MD5 : 5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3
JV MD5 : 5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3

Message : The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
my MD5 : 9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6
JV MD5 : 9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6

Message : 11111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888999999999900000000001111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888899999999990000000000
my MD5 : 61b7deb6c10abea9e621a228073473e9
JV MD5 : 6290364f4986f468e351f14e38c8a737
```

EDIT:
Here is the test code...

public class Md5Hash {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     String[] messages = { "", "bca", "helmo", "hello world", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "11111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888999999999900000000001111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888899999999990000000000"
     };

    for (String message : messages) {
        System.out.println("Message : " + message);
        System.out.println("my MD5 : " + md5DigestHexString(message));
        System.out.println("JV MD5 : " + md5DigestJavaHexString(message));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And here is the code that makes use of the JDK's implementation:

```
public static String md5DigestJavaHexString(String message) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    MessageDigest md;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(message.getBytes());
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        for (byte b : digest) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I see two problems so far, and I've fixed two of your test cases.  I'm having an issue with the last test case, so I'll keep looking.  Can you show me what code you used for your test cases?

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the original post to include the code I use for my test cases.

Comment: Thanks, but what is `md5DigestJavaHexString`?

Comment: It's a very poor name choice for the function that takes a string as an input and outputs the string representing the md5 hash.

Comment: Can you add those methods to your question?

Comment: Here is the code of md5DigestJavaHexString. Actually the two extra methods I had copy-pasted weren't implemented. Sorry that it was confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using an IDE, you'll see that the following conditions are incorrect:

```
if (0 <= j && j <= 15) {

} else if (16 <= j & j <= 31) {

} else if (32 <= j && j <= 47) {

} else if (48 <= j && j <= 63) {

}
```

The first condition `0 <= j` is **always true**.  Changing the conditions to the following helps to fix your issue:

```
if (j <= 15) {

} else if (j <= 31) {

} else if (j <= 47) {

} else if (j <= 63) {

}
```

Secondly, the following code does not get the correct value of the chunk (it should be little endian):

```
int chunk = finalTabForMsgInBytesToDigest[i + g * 4 + 3] << 24;
chunk |= finalTabForMsgInBytesToDigest[i + g * 4 + 2] << 16;
chunk |= finalTabForMsgInBytesToDigest[i + g * 4 + 1] << 8;
chunk |= finalTabForMsgInBytesToDigest[i + g * 4];
```

You can use the following instead (**inside the first loop**):

```
IntBuffer intBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(finalTabForMsgInBytesToDigest).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer();
int[] array = new int[16];  // We're storing 16 integers each iteration.
intBuf.get(new int[i / 4]); // Skip integers that we've already used.
intBuf.get(array);          // Get the next 16 integers.
int chunk = array[g];       // Save the chunk.
```

After these changes are made, all of your test cases pass!